# bash: /home/x/.bash_profile: Permission denied. How to fix this issue?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to open the bash_profile file but it gives the following result

```
~/.bash_profile 
bash: /home/x/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

After searching  I found this solution on the internet

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

But this command gives the following output

```
The program 'the' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install the
```

when I typed it gives this result

```
sudo apt install
[sudo] password for x:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not upgraded.
x@ubuntu:~$ source ~/.bash_profile
The program 'the' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install the
```

please help me how to fix it.

Thank you All.

Comment: can you  show the content of the .bash_profile file ? cat ~/.bash_profile

Comment: That is the problem it not opening the bash_profile

Comment: if the ouput of the .bash_profile is "the", can you run vi ~/.bash_profile ? and you see inside the file only "the"

Comment: yes it showing only "the"

Comment: ok then. Let me answer then the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the clarifications, let me tell you what is happening.

The ~/.bash_profile file is a configuration file for configuring user environments. The users can modify the default settings and add any extra configurations on it. In your case, the file is empty and it is throwing an error because inside the file you have the word "the".

You Linux Server is trying to run the command "the", so the reason for the error you are getting is that you have no execution privileges over it. I've never ever heard of a program called "the", but giving your error perhaps the program is there. If the program did not exist, you would have gotten "No such file or directory".

Replace the content of the .bash_profile with the minimum content you need for this kind of file:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export PATH=.:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

For viewing the bash_profile:
`cat ~/.bash_profile`

For editing:
`vi ~/.bash_profile`

If you get a permission denied, use sudo before `cat` or `vi` commands.

Comment: I just run the cat ~/.bash_profile it gives the following result x@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/.bash_profile
the only output is "the" nothing else showing

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

And for only creating your own without editing it...

```
set -x && $(type -p touch) ${HOME}"/.bash_profile"; set +x
```

... if already exists then only the modification time is changing.
I wrote the simple command cryptic because `set -x` shows what going on and `set +x` exits the debug mode.